# I'd like to make my discord slash command only usable for admins

Tags: permissions, discord.py, command, roles, slash

I want this command only usable for those who has one of my 3 specific roles.

```
@bot.tree.command(name = "addrole", description = "Rangadás", guild=discord.Object(id=my server's id))
async def addrole(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{member.mention}-ra ráadva: `{role.name}`!")
```

How can I make it?
Thank you for your help!

I tried like this:

```
@bot.tree.command(name = "addrole", description = "Rangadás", guild=discord.Object(id=my server's id))
@commands.has_any_roles(id1, id2, id3)
async def addrole(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{member.mention}-ra ráadva: `{role.name}`!")
```

Answer (score 0):

### How this works

Using [guild_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.guild_permissions) (under the member class) with type [permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions) we can check if a member has admin.

### Code

```
if interaction.user.guild_permissions.admin:
    #Add the code that you want to run
else:
    #Add error message
```

### Resources

- [Permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions)